# How do I get the job object (if any) for my current process?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, process

In the context of Windows [Job Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161(VS.85).aspx), how can I get the job object for the current process (in case it is in a job object)? The [IsProcessInJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684127(VS.85).aspx) function lets me test whether a given process (e.g. the current one) is in a given (or any) job - but it doesn't yield the handle of the matching job.

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but I think this link might be useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc907078%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It looks like there is no documented method to do this.  You can enumerate all the processes that belong to a specific job, but you can't enumerate all the jobs.  There are undocumented methods, though...

Comment: @Luke: Undocumented methods? Do tell! :-)

Comment: @Luke, undocumented method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you just want to find out what quotas/limits you are running under, or enumerate all the other processes in the job, you don't need to get the Job object for the current process.

You can call `QueryInformationJobObject` with NULL, which will be the Job object of the current process.

- QueryInformationJobObject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684925(VS.85).aspx
- Job Objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161(VS.85).aspx
- Set job attributes using `SetInformationJobObject`

To answer the specific question, call `IsProcessInJob` find out if you are in a job.

You can find out everything about the Job by passing NULL to `QueryInformationJobObject`

Your child processes will inherit your job automatically, unless you pass `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` **and** the job has `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK`  or `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SILENT_BREAKAWAY_OK` is set. In these cases you can assign the process to a new job if you wish.

So without knowing the handle, you can find out all about your current Job, and assign child processes within the current job, or if you have permission, without the current job. I.e. you can do almost everything the handle would allow you to do.

The only exception is duplicate it to another sibling process. If you need to do that you will have to have the parent process communicate the handle value to you somehow.

Comment: Not quite; I want to start a sub process and if I'm running in a job object myself, I want to assign the sub process to my current job. For this, I need to get a handle on my current job.

Comment: Your sub process will inherit the current job. You do not need to assign it. This happens automatically, you don't have to do anything to achieve this.

Comment: True, my comment was incomplete, sorry. What makes this tricky is that If I'm *not* running in a job object myself, I want to create a new job myself and then assign the sub process to that.

Comment: OK well I think it is answered above then. Create the process with the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag, and get the handles from `PROCESS_INFORMATION`. Check if you are in a job using `IsProcessInJob`, if false, create a Job object call `AssignProcessToJobObject`. Call `ResumeThread`, and close the process and thread handles (unless you need to keep them).

Comment: @Ben How can We set JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK for the job?